# AppAuth for android - hide logout screen

Tags: appauth

I have an Android app developed in JAVA. For this app I am using the IdentityServer4 and AppAuth library implementation (found here: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) . Everything works fine, but one annoying thing left.

Can anyone help me with hide logout screen from identity server?

Example redirects logout to the one sent by server, what doesn't need to be displayed.

I really don't want to show it to end user.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: do you find any way